# Referring to variables in another terraform file you can't modify

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I'm using a tool named [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) that generates a terraform file to set up some infrastructure for kubernetes.  After that, we want to use terraform to create parts of our infrastructure specific to our application.  e.g., a queue, a proxy, elasticache, etc.

The terraform file that kops generates has a lot of information in it that I'd like to refer to when creating the queue/proxy/elasticache.  e.g., the subnet ranges to use, the cidr blocks, the availability zones, etc.  But, I don't want to modify the kops generated terraform file because whenever there's a kops upgrade, I'll have to re-generate it then re-modify it.

The terraform file that kops generates doesn't provide any `output` variables.  I could append my queue/proxy/elasticache configurations to the bottom of the file that kops generates.  Then I'd be able to refer to the kops generated variables.  But I consider this to be a modification to the kops generated file and would like to avoid this for the reasons above.

How can I make my custom terraform reference the parts of a generated terraform file?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no output variables in the generated terraform files and you do not want to change them, how about using data sources?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

> Data sources allow data to be fetched or computed for use elsewhere in Terraform configuration. Use of data sources allows a Terraform configuration to build on information defined outside of Terraform, or defined by another separate Terraform configuration.